# what are the numbers in bracket against chain name in iptable?

Tags: iptables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don’t understand [0:0] iptable syntax](https://serverfault.com/questions/373871/dont-understand-00-iptable-syntax)

iptable-save command gives something like following output

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [45:2658]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [78:4056]
:ufw-after-forward - [0:0]
```

what is the meaning of range of numbers give in square bracket? like in [45: 2658]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A chain specification looks like : `chain-name` `chain-policy`
>   [`packet-counter`:`byte-counter`]. The `chain-name` may be for example
>   PREROUTING, the policy is described previously and can for example be
>   ACCEPT. Finally the `packet-counter` and `byte-counters` are the same
>   counters as in the output from `iptables -L -v`.

http://www.faqs.org/docs/iptables/iptables-save.html